# Two different attribute symbology in QGIS

Tags: qgis-3

I have protected species map in which I have different attributes two of them are taxon group and common names. I want to display the symbol that within  each taxon group I can display the common names as well. please assist

Comment: Your question is not clear, are you asking how to classify your data with two field for symbology purpose or how to label with two field or how to classify on one field but have two field in legend or ... ? please clarify